# luatexja with microtype generates lots of warnings

Tags: fontspec, microtype, luatexja

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\begin{document}
Lot's of Warnings.
\end{document}
```

The above sample throws a boatload of errors of the type

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\textgreater '
(microtype)                in font encoding `EU2' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `T1-default'.
```

The intention is to have a document with Japanese, Chinese, Russian, English and German. For the languages that support it I would want microtype support. Is this possible? Is luatexja the right approach here?

EDIT: Sorry, I dropped an important line here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{NimbusSansL.otf}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
Lot's of Warnings.
\end{document}
```

Comment: From what I can see, the functionality remains unaffected so far. Can you please enlighten me though as to what these errors are actually trying to tell me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following document shows no `microtype` warning, because the package is loaded at the right time, that is, after the font related packages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

No warning.

\end{document}
```

Here's the terminal output

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./lots.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty))(usi
ng write cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/ge
neric)(using read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic 
/Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@kernpair = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@ligacomp = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@markbase = 3
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@markmark = 4
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@markdone = 5
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@cursbase = 6
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@curscurs = 7
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@cursdone = 8
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 9
luaotfload | main : fontloader loaded in 0.020 seconds
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.find_vf_file' at position 1 in `find_vf_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everyhook/everyhook.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svn-prov/svn-prov.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
Custom whatsit inhibitglue = 1
Custom whatsit stack_marker = 2
Custom whatsit begin_par = 3
Custom whatsit direction = 4(load cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/
texmf-var/luatexja/ltj-cid-auto-adobe-japan1.luc)
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' at position 1 in `vpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' at position 1 in `pre_output_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' at position 1 in `buildpage_filter'.
Module luatexbase Warning: resetting exclusive callback: define_font on input li
ne 179
Removing  `luaotfload.define_font' from `define_font'.
Inserting `luatexja.font_callback' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' at position 1 in `luatexja.define_font'.
Inserting `1' at position 1 in `luatexja.define_jfont'.
Removing  `ltj.prepare_extra_data' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.supply_tounicode' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
Inserting `ltj.process_input_buffer' at position 1 in `process_input_buffer'.
Inserting `ltj.hyphenate' at position 1 in `hyphenate'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.hpack_filter_pre' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter_pre' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'
.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 2 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luatexja.beginpar.np_info' at position 1 in `luatexja.jfmglue.whatsit
_getinfo'.
Inserting `luatexja.beginpar.np_info_after' at position 1 in `luatexja.jfmglue.w
hatsit_after'.
Inserting `ltj.mlist_to_hlist' at position 1 in `mlist_to_hlist'.
Inserting `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter' at position 3 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.hpack_filter' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 4 in `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter_pre' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.adjust_icflag' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter_pre' at position 2 in `pre_linebreak_filter'
.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 3 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter' at position 4 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.hpack_filter_pre' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.hpack_filter' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.adjust_icflag' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.hpack_filter_pre' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.hpack_filter' at position 4 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 5 in `hpack_filter'.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-latex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjfont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty)
ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjdefs.sty(com
piling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ipa
exm.luc)(load luc: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache
/generic/fonts/otf/ipaexm.luc)(load cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/201
5/texmf-var/luatexja/extra_ipaexm.luc)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujisv.lua)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujis.lua))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjcore.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-geometry.
sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-compat.sty(load
 cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatexja/ltj-jisx0208.l
uc))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-luatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(./lots.aux) ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg) [1{/usr/loca
l/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./lots.aux))
 2374 words of node memory still in use:
   9 hlist, 1 vlist, 4 rule, 3 glue, 9 kern, 2 glyph, 610 attribute, 194 glue_sp
ec, 38 attribute_list, 1 write, 1 pdf_setmatrix, 1 pdf_save, 1 pdf_restore, 11 u
ser_defined nodes
   avail lists: 1:3,2:1097,3:6,4:48,5:3,6:41,7:4,9:14,10:2
<</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on lots.pdf (1 page, 12789 bytes).
Transcript written on lots.log.
```

This is the terminal output when loading `luatexja-fontspec`:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./lots.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/addons/luatexja-fontspe
c.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty))(usi
ng write cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/ge
neric)(using read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic 
/Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@kernpair = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@ligacomp = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@markbase = 3
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@markmark = 4
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@markdone = 5
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@cursbase = 6
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@curscurs = 7
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@cursdone = 8
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 9
luaotfload | main : fontloader loaded in 0.020 seconds
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.find_vf_file' at position 1 in `find_vf_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everyhook/everyhook.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svn-prov/svn-prov.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
Custom whatsit inhibitglue = 1
Custom whatsit stack_marker = 2
Custom whatsit begin_par = 3
Custom whatsit direction = 4(load cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/
texmf-var/luatexja/ltj-cid-auto-adobe-japan1.luc)
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' at position 1 in `vpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' at position 1 in `pre_output_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' at position 1 in `buildpage_filter'.
Module luatexbase Warning: resetting exclusive callback: define_font on input li
ne 179
Removing  `luaotfload.define_font' from `define_font'.
Inserting `luatexja.font_callback' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' at position 1 in `luatexja.define_font'.
Inserting `1' at position 1 in `luatexja.define_jfont'.
Removing  `ltj.prepare_extra_data' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.supply_tounicode' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
Inserting `ltj.process_input_buffer' at position 1 in `process_input_buffer'.
Inserting `ltj.hyphenate' at position 1 in `hyphenate'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.hpack_filter_pre' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter_pre' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'
.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 2 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luatexja.beginpar.np_info' at position 1 in `luatexja.jfmglue.whatsit
_getinfo'.
Inserting `luatexja.beginpar.np_info_after' at position 1 in `luatexja.jfmglue.w
hatsit_after'.
Inserting `ltj.mlist_to_hlist' at position 1 in `mlist_to_hlist'.
Inserting `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter' at position 3 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.hpack_filter' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 4 in `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter_pre' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.adjust_icflag' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter_pre' at position 2 in `pre_linebreak_filter'
.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 3 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.pre_linebreak_filter' at position 4 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.hpack_filter_pre' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.hpack_filter' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.adjust_icflag' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.hpack_filter_pre' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.hpack_filter' at position 4 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 5 in `hpack_filter'.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-latex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjfont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty)
ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjdefs.sty(com
piling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ipa
exm.luc)(load luc: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache
/generic/fonts/otf/ipaexm.luc)(load cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/201
5/texmf-var/luatexja/extra_ipaexm.luc)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujisv.lua)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujis.lua))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjcore.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-geometry.
sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-compat.sty(load
 cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatexja/ltj-jisx0208.l
uc))) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmr.fd)(compiling luc: /u
sr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-regular
.luc)(load luc: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/ge
neric/fonts/otf/lmroman10-regular.luc)(load cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/tex
live/2015/texmf-var/luatexja/extra_lmroman10-regular.luc))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def(compiling luc: /usr
/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmromanslant10-regu
lar.luc)(load luc: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache
/generic/fonts/otf/lmromanslant10-regular.luc)(load cache: /Users/enrico2013/Lib
rary/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatexja/extra_lmromanslant10-regular.luc)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT3/mc/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `JT3/mc/m/n' instead on input line 316.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JY3/mc/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `JY3/mc/m/n' instead on input line 316.

(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf
/lmroman10-italic.luc)(load luc: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-va
r/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-italic.luc)(load cache: /Users/enrico
2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatexja/extra_lmroman10-italic.luc)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT3/mc/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `JT3/mc/m/n' instead on input line 316.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JY3/mc/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `JY3/mc/m/n' instead on input line 316.

(compiling luc: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf
/lmroman10-bold.luc)(load luc: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-bold.luc)(load cache: /Users/enrico2013
/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatexja/extra_lmroman10-bold.luc)(compiling luc
: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ipaexg.luc)(l
oad luc: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/f
onts/otf/ipaexg.luc)(load cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-va
r/luatexja/extra_ipaexg.luc)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmss.fd)(compiling luc: /
usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmsans10-regular
.luc)(load luc: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/ge
neric/fonts/otf/lmsans10-regular.luc)(load cache: /Users/enrico2013/Library/texl
ive/2015/texmf-var/luatexja/extra_lmsans10-regular.luc))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/addons/luatexja-fontspe
c-24.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-luatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(./lots.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-fontspec.
sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-xunicode.
sty (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
*** Reloading Xunicode for encoding 'EU2' ***
)) ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./lots.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

)
 2393 words of node memory still in use:
   10 hlist, 1 vlist, 4 rule, 3 glue, 9 kern, 2 glyph, 611 attribute, 196 glue_s
pec, 38 attribute_list, 1 write, 1 pdf_setmatrix, 1 pdf_save, 1 pdf_restore, 11 
user_defined nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:1138,3:6,4:48,5:3,6:41,7:4,9:14,10:2
</Library/Fonts/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on lots.pdf (1 page, 3977 bytes).
Transcript written on lots.log.
```

As you can see, there's no `microtype` warning either.

---

Now, what happens when you define a main font different from the default? In the default case, the `mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg` file is read in, which contains instructions for character inheritance and protrusion. With another font, if there's not a corresponding `.cfg` file, the standard one is used, which contains several instructions that are not useful with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX (for example all the accented characters).

The warnings are innocuous, but quite annoying. You can silence them with the `silence` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{silence}

\WarningFilter{microtype}{Unknown slot number of character}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
No warning.
\end{document}
```

Of course, a better way of avoiding the warnings would be to provide an appropriate `.cfg` file.

Comment: That's not really true I think. If I load `microtype` before `luatexja` (without fontspec) it also doesn't generate and error but if I load it after and use `luatexja-fontspec` then I still get the error. I tried this out beforehand. To me it appears as if the order doesn't matter at al just that these two packages are incompatible in some subtle sense.

Comment: @Max Even if I load `luatexja-fontspec` I get no warning. Check you have the latest versions.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I was too tired when I tried it.

Comment: Turns out I lost a line in my sample. If you add 
`\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{NimbusSansL.otf}` between `luatexja-fontspec` and `microtype` then it is not dependent on the order.

Comment: @Max As far as I can see, they are just annoying warnings due to the code in `microtype.cfg`, that should be fixed. I added a note.